# How to Read Attributes from Grails Externalized Properties Files in Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, grails-config

I have added an externalized properties file in `Config.groovy` file. Such as:

```
grails.config.locations << "file:app-test-config.properties"
```

And this how my externalized properties `file app-test-config.properties` look like:

> ```
> SERVER_IP_ADDRESS = 123.456.789.0
> SERVER_PORT= 1234
> ```

I am using AngularJs framework and I have a javascript file in `assets` directory. Now, I want to access the server IP and Port in that javascript file.

How this can be possible? Is there any way to use `Holder` or `grailsApplication` in javascript file to read attributes from externalized properties file?

Comment: In a pure js file you need to make an ajax call to read these properties

Comment: Yes this was in my mind, but I am trying to avoid from making call to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a controller action as following:

```
class JavaScriptController {

  def grailsApplication
  def config() {
    String config = "${grailsApplication.config.flatten() as JSON}"
    String content = "config= ${config}"   
    render contentType: 'text/javascript', text: content
  }

}
```

Haven't tested the above code but the idea is to push a javascript file which will contain all the config as javascript object. You can apply caching/cloudfront to this response so that your server don't get many requests.